# "so as to... and that"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I wanted to reveal the facts as they were ***so as to*** save your
> reputation ***and that*** your sponsors might regain their trust in
> you.

The subject of the ***so as to*** clause is I, but the subject of the ***and that*** clause is different (your sponsors). Is it correct to coordinate such clauses with different subjects and in the second  one to change from ***so as to*** to ***(so) that***?

Comment: Both clauses are clauses of purpose, that connect to 'to reveal". But the phrasing is strange. Also, your original sentence doesn't have "so that", but just "that", which sounds antiquated. Where is the sentence from?

Comment: I am translating a book from Greek. It has a certain style. in the **and that** clause, I assumed **so** was elided.